# Misunderstanding of SPECIALIZE pragma

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-warnings

The purpose of the `SPECIALIZE` pragma is to create more specific version of function.

I have a function

```
adaptBlocks :: Int -> BlocksField a -> Maybe (BlocksField a)
```

and I specialized it as follows:

```
{-# SPECIALIZE NOINLINE
    adaptBlocks :: Int -> BlocksField Element -> Maybe (BlocksField Element) #-}
```

But the compiler gives me this confusing warning:

```
SPECIALISE pragma for non-overloaded function ‘adaptBlocks’
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What performance improvement do you imagine you would get from this specialized version? How should the generated code be different from the unspecialized one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specialization works on bounded polymorphism, where type variables such as `a` are constrained, e.g.

```
foo :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
foo x y | x == y    = 2*x
        | otherwise = 3*y
```

Here, specializing `a ~ Int` allows the compiler to inline the `Int` versions of `(==),(*)`, improving efficiency. Note that such functions are provided by the context `(Eq a, Num a)`.

In your case, there is no context that constrains `a`, so this optimization can not be performed. After all your polymorphic code can not use `(*)` or any other numeric function on the `Int`, since in order to compile, your code must handle any type `a`, including those which are not numbers.

Comment: This SPECIALIZE is useless but valid according to docs:
{-# SPECIALIZE f :: <type> #-}
is valid if and only if the definition
f_spec :: <type>
f_spec = f
is valid

See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#specialize-pragma So probably it is documentation bug?

Comment: @Yuras, perhaps. It's only a warning; valid code can validly trigger warnings.